# Filtering data from one sheet to another in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to have data stored on one sheet like a database, and then one displayed on another sheet based filtered by product. I am not familiar with visual basic at all, yet my boss tasked me with this project.

Basically we have a variable name, variable type, and a product that those will be associated with. New names, types, and even products will most likely be added in the future. I can't seem to find a solution online that will allow me to filter on one page while pulling data from another.

This is how the data sheet looks like at the moment. This was the best way we could think of for future expansion of the data sheet as multiple products would be associated with one new variable.

```
Name | Type | Product | Product | Product...|
test | var  | Product |         | Product   |
test2| txt  | Product |         |           |
test3| char |         | Product | Product   |
```

I hope this makes sense and if anyone can help that would be great. Below is some code we have found online and have tried to modify it to work with no luck.

```
Dim myButton As OptionButton
Dim MyVal As Long
Dim ButtonName As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myField As Long
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim mySearch As Variant

'Load Sheet into A Variable

  Set sht = ActiveSheet
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Activate

'Unfilter Data (if necessary)
  On Error Resume Next
    sht.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)

  Set DataRange = sht.Range("A1:Z1000") 'Cell Range
  'Set DataRange = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range 'Table

'Retrieve User's Search Input
  mySearch = sht.Shapes("UserSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text 'Control Form
  'mySearch = sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text 'ActiveX Control
  'mySearch = sht.Range("A1").Value 'Cell Input

'Loop Through Option Buttons
  For Each myButton In ActiveSheet.OptionButtons
      If myButton.Value = 1 Then
        ButtonName = myButton.Text
        Exit For
      End If
  Next myButton

'Determine Filter Field
  On Error GoTo HeadingNotFound
    myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Filter Data
  DataRange.AutoFilter _
    Field:=myField, _
    Criteria1:="=*" & mySearch & "*", _
    Operator:=xlAnd

'Clear Search Field
  sht.Shapes("UserSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "" 'Control Form
  'sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text = "" 'ActiveX Control
  'sht.Range("A1").Value = "" 'Cell Input

Exit Sub

'ERROR HANDLERS
HeadingNotFound:
  MsgBox "The column heading [" & ButtonName & "] was not found in cells " & DataRange.Rows(1).Address & ". " & _
    vbNewLine & "Please check for possible typos.", vbCritical, "Header Name Not Found!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest that I've used was actually a kinda clunky equation:

Hidden_Sheet: Hidden table

B5978: Product Filter

$A$2:$A$5997: Full range on hidden table where 'Product filter' will look. I don't think you can make it simply $a:$a.

$E$2:$E$5997: Value you want to return

**$A$2: This does need to change in each row of your final sheet (i.e. "$A$2," $A$3," etc.).**

```
=IF(B5978=0,"",IFERROR(INDEX(Hidden_Sheet!$E$2:$E$5997,SMALL(INDEX((B5978=Hidden_Sheet!$A$2:$A$5997)*(MATCH(ROW(Hidden_Sheet!$A$2:$A$5997),ROW(Hidden_Sheet!$A$2:$A$5997)))+(B5978<>Hidden_Sheet!$A$2:$A$5997)*1048577,0,0),ROW(Hidden_Sheet!$A$2))),""))
```